# How to patch Python in order to insert BreakPoints using IDLE on MAC

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

A patch **issue6075_py3k.patch** from [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue6075) is supposed to fix this problem. In the terminal, I copied the patch file into **Idlelib** directory where Bindings.py and EditorWindow.py are located and proceeded by typing **patch -p2 issue6075_py3k.patch**. The patch was successful. I fired up IDLE and I still can't use Breakpoints. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Python did you patch?  And which directory?  There are various reason why it might not work. Make sure you are trying to use it correctly. You need to left click on a source line in an IDLE editor window while holding the Control key to set a breakpoint there.  Then you'll need to enable the IDLE Debugger, when the Shell window is active, before running the program.

EDIT: The Issue6075 patch does not address the IDLE breakpoints problem (that is for building with Cocoa Tk 8.5, not an issue for the Python 3.1 installer).  The breakpoint problem is covered in [Issue 10404](http://bugs.python.org/issue10404); download and install the [patch for it](http://bugs.python.org/file19592/issue10404-idle_no_context_menus.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the patch. I'm using Python 3.1 which is installed in Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/idlelib.  Isn't a breakpoint supposed to highlight the line of text? It's still not working for me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice initially: Issue 6075 is the wrong patch for the problem.  See edited answer.

Comment: Great. BTW, on StackOverflow, it is expected that, when you post a question and receive an answer, you'll either mark the answer as accepted (so that the answerer receives reputation points and the questioner doesn't get flagged) or refine the question until you get an acceptable answer.